# deleting border elements in excel using C#

Tags: c#, winforms

in the code below I use the EPPlus package to delete some table formatation in Excel:

```
             using (var package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(filePath)))
            {
                var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[worksheetName];

                var ranges = new[] { "AT7", "BE7:BJ7", "AT9", "BJ9", "AT14", "BE14:BJ14", "AT16", "BJ16" };

                foreach (var range in ranges)
                {
                    var cells = worksheet.Cells[range];
                    cells.Style.Border.Top.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.None;
                    cells.Style.Border.Bottom.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.None;
                }

                var anoranges = new[] { "BJ11", "BJ18" };

                foreach (var i in anoranges)
                {
                    var cells = worksheet.Cells[i];
                    cells.Style.Border.Top.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.None;
                }

                package.Save();
            }
```

the problem is it doesn't remove that border formatation in the given address, I've already tried with the ClosedXML as well, but still the result is the same.

I've already tried use the functional paradigm to basically write it as a function, but that didn't seem to affect the result, and I've already tried with the ClosedXML as well, but still the result is the same.

Comment: Set the border style to ExcelBorderStyle.None for all sides (Top, Bottom, Left, Right) for each cell in the specified ranges.